# Android in app pop-up window with Listview and buttons

Tags: android

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Crappy Design]

Basically I want a sort of a dialog type pop-up window,
That displays a list of installed apps, with a button next to them.
This is for a custom launcher I'm working on, How would one go about doing this?
I'm looking for suggestions in what kind of direction I should start looking, And which android services would be optional to use in this case.

Here's the basics I use for finding specified apps I want in the list:

```
    private ArrayList<AppDetail> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages, String filter) {
    ArrayList<AppDetail> res = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue;
        }
        AppDetail newInfo = new AppDetail();
        newInfo.name = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        if (newInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
            if(!newInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("launcher")) {
                res.add(newInfo);
            }           
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. 

StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Comment: @EdGeorge I'm not looking for code, I am just looking for someone to send me in the right direction. What kind of method's there would be to going about doing this. Suggestions merely.

Comment: Your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. You haven't demonstrated that you have began to attempt to solve this - showing your code for getting a list of available apps would be a good start.

Comment: @EdGeorge There you go